# Wordpress php IF statement for displaying HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

I added the code below to my Wordpress template but it's not processing...

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
    <p>test</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>visitor</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Add `global $user;` maybe something has altered it.

Comment: i viewed the source code and the PHP is being commented out

Comment: how did you add this? Modifying the template files directly or using the CMS editor system? It seems too simple to fail on its own, so the only thing I can figure is it is being added to a file that is not being called. Do you see "visitor" or nothing?

Comment: Where are people picking up this ugly syntax? VB is dead. Use curly-brackets.

Comment: @developerwjk its the easiest way I know of how to added in HTML with php

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code. It will work.

```
<?php if( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
        <p>test</p>
<?php } else { ?>
        <p>visitor</p>
<?php } ?>
```